# Not clear on what this variable setting does: var a = !1

Tags: javascript

I've seen a explanation for something similar to b = !b. But I'm not understanding it well enough to translate over to this usage.

What does

```
var a = !1;
```

do?

Comment: It means that `a` is `false`, and it's pretty useless. Maybe the `1` is being output from the server side? Then it could make some sense.

Comment: @bfavaretto 3 bytes saved. Heroic.

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to dissect code to try and get a better understanding of different programming methods and i've been seeing a lot of snippets that have turned out to be convoluted ways of doing simple things.

Comment: `!` is a logical NOT (`!!` is a negation operator), so if you put `!` in front of a value, it will get "negated" to it's opposite boolean value. `!true == false`, `!!true == true`, `!false == true`, etc. `1` evaluates as boolean `true`, so `!1 == false`. It's more useful when you need a boolean value of some non-boolean expression.

Answer (score 6):

`a = !1` is a shorthand way of writing `a = false`. This is normally used when trying to compress (minify) JavaScript because it saves three bytes.

If you're seeing this in ordinary un-minified JS, then someone is probably being either lazy or obfuscatory.

Comment: Not only 3 bytes, but 3 keystrokes saved. Time === money, someone is being SMART! `sarcastic-face.gif`

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Making other developers have to ask StackOverflow to figure out your two bytes is not smart.

Comment: Maybe we're being trolled.

Comment: Don't forget, ! costs you one extra Shift keystroke. So only two keystrokes saved.

Answer (score 1):

Run this in chrome dev tools and see what you get.

**a** evaluates to false because 1 is a *truthy* value in javascript and therefore negating it produces *false*

Maybe read this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/ . It's quite interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

In general the `!` will invert the boolean value of its operand.

So `!a` will be `true` if `a` is `false` or it will be `false` if `a` is `true`.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`!` is a `not` operator. Therefore `! true` is equal to `false`. It's result will be either `true` or `false`

All values in JavaScript are either "truthy" or "falsy". This describes their interpretation in contexts where a `boolean` (`true` or `false`) is expected.

Examples of "truthy" values: true, 1, [], {}, "text"

Examples of "falsy" values: false, 0, ""

`!1` is a negation of a truthy value, which will evalute to false. `b = !b` is a `toggler`, it will change the value from a `truthy` to a `falsy`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` operator is known as the [Logical NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29) operator.

In short, it returns `false` if the following value is 'truthy', and `true` otherwise.

Since `1` is 'truthy', your example, `!1` reads `NOT 1`, which will return `false`.